# Sharetribe installation rake aborted

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpacker, sharetribe

When trying to install sharetribe, and following the procedure, I type :

```
bundle exec rake db:create db:structure:load
```

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ReactOnRails::WebpackerUtils::Webpacker
/Users/user/code/blaisepop/sharetribe/sharetribe/config/initializers/react_on_rails.rb:13:in `<main>'
/Users/user/code/blaisepop/sharetribe/sharetribe/config/environment.rb:28:in `<main>'
./bin/bundle:3:in `load'
./bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
```